# \u221c unicode doesn't show on button

Tags: android, button, unicode

my problem is that I can't put '\u221c' unicode on button in Android app. '\u221a' is OK and works, but 221b and 221c doesn't. Also, when I want that button to put text '\u221c' in EditText it puts \u221a. I dont know why it works that way and how to fix this. Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This appears to be simply a font problem. U+221A SQUARE ROOT “√” is a much more common character in fonts than U+221B CUBE ROOT “∛” and U+221C FOURTH ROOT “∜”. You may need to find a font that contains them and bundle it into the application, or use other notations.

You can, in particular, use fractional powers instead of roots. That’s even the preferred way, according to the standard ISO 80000-2. So instead of ∜a, you would use “a” followed by “1/4” in superscript style, if that’s possible in the application.